# How do I install 2 different windows services with 1 setup project?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have 2 different windows services that should be installed by a single setup project. The project output from both of them goes into the same directory which is fine. There is a project installer and a service installer added under each of their respective projects. But for some reason it is only one of the services that are installed (similar to installutil /i MyServiceA), but the other one is not. So after install I have to manually type installutil /i MyServiceB. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single project installer class which will contain your service and process installers of both both / all services.

For example

```
MyProjectInstaller
    -> MyFirstServiceInstaller
    -> MyFirstServiceProcessInstaller
    -> MySecondServiceInstaller
    -> MySecondServiceProcessInstaller
```

However, each class with the `RunInstaller(true)` attribute *should* technically  be executed regardless of having neighbours, or not; to this end, maybe someone has a more direct approach to your problem.

Comment: That is what I have now. But second windows service is never installed. What am I missing?